# Summability of a sinc function power 'p', where 1<p<2

Tags: sequences-and-series, signal-processing

We know that a sum of the form 
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left|\frac{sin(a\pi n)}{a\pi n}\right|$ where $a$ *is not an integer*, is unbounded and tends to infinity. But what about the expression
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left|\frac{sin(a\pi n)}{a\pi n}\right|^p$ where $1<p<2$. Would anyone please provide some insight on this?

Comment: $\operatorname{sin}(\pi n) = 0$ for any $n\in \mathbf{N}$. Is there any ambiguity to be revised in your description?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out Ansel. There were alot of thoughts going through my head when i jotted this down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|\sin(a\pi n)|\le1$ and the potential series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-p}$ converges if and only if $p>1$, the comparison principle implies that your series converges for all $p>1$.

Comment: Thank you Julian. Would you know of any way to get a closed form of the expression?

Comment: Using Fourier series you can check that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(a\pi n)}{a\pi n}=1+\frac{1-a}{2a}$. For the sums with absolute value, I have no idea of how to get a closed expression for its value.

Comment: About my previous comment: the value of the sum is valid for $0< a<2$.